# MySQL Server 5.6 won't start on Windows

Tags: mysql-5.6, windows-server

I'm having an issue getting MySQL Server 5.6 (community edition) running. It was working just fine until I restarted my server. Now it won't start at all.

After doing a bit of research, I discovered there is a log file that it writes to, which has helped a little, but I'm not entirely sure how to fix the issue it's reporting.

After doing more research I discovered trying to start mysqld manually using the options "--standalone" and "--debug" might help, but they don't seem to make a difference, and I've looked everywhere for the mysterious debug log, but was unable to find it. I checked in the C drive root, and in MySQL server folders, but nothing. Here is the most recent .err file report:

> 2014-09-18 18:47:29 2240 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
>
> 2014-09-18 18:47:29 2240 [Note] InnoDB: Using atomics to ref count buffer pool pages
>
> 2014-09-18 18:47:29 2240 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 2014-09-18 18:47:29 2240 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use Windows interlocked functions
>
> 2014-09-18 18:47:29 2240 [Note] InnoDB: Memory barrier is not used
>
> 2014-09-18 18:47:29 2240 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
>
> 2014-09-18 18:47:29 2240 [Note] InnoDB: Not using CPU crc32 instructions
>
> 2014-09-18 18:47:29 2240 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, size = 128.0M
>
> 2014-09-18 18:47:29 2240 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
>
> 2014-09-18 18:47:33 2240 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
>
> 2014-09-18 18:47:33 2240 [Note] InnoDB: The log sequence numbers 1625977 and 1625977 in ibdata 
>   files do not match the log sequence number 28347554 in the ib_logfiles!
>
> 2014-09-18 18:47:33 2240 [Note] InnoDB: Database was not shutdown normally!
>
> 2014-09-18 18:47:33 2240 [Note] InnoDB: Starting crash recovery.
>
> 2014-09-18 18:47:33 2240 [Note] InnoDB: Reading tablespace information from the .ibd files...
>
> 2014-09-18 18:47:34 2240 [ERROR] InnoDB: Attempted to open a previously opened tablespace. Previous 
>   tablespace osticket/ost_ticket__cdata uses space ID: 54 at filepath: .\osticket\ost_ticket__cdata.ibd. Cannot open tablespace osticket_2/ost_api_key which uses space ID: 54 at filepath: .\osticket_2\ost_api_key.ibd
>
> InnoDB: Error: could not open single-table tablespace file .\osticket_2\ost_api_key.ibd
>
> InnoDB: We do not continue the crash recovery, because the table may become
>
> InnoDB: corrupt if we cannot apply the log records in the InnoDB log to it.
>
> InnoDB: To fix the problem and start mysqld:
>
> InnoDB: 1) If there is a permission problem in the file and mysqld cannot
>
> InnoDB: open the file, you should modify the permissions.
>
> InnoDB: 2) If the table is not needed, or you can restore it from a backup,
>
> InnoDB: then you can remove the .ibd file, and InnoDB will do a normal
>
> InnoDB: crash recovery and ignore that table.
>
> InnoDB: 3) If the file system or the disk is broken, and you cannot remove
>
> InnoDB: the .ibd file, you can set innodb_force_recovery > 0 in my.cnf
>
> InnoDB: and force InnoDB to continue crash recovery here.

Any clue as to what might fix this problem? I'd prefer a solution that doesn't involve losing my MySQL database files/entries, as I've already had to redo over half of my SQL-connected web services, and would prefer not to have to do it again.

Answer (score 2):

[closed] Reinstalled MySQL, removed old DB's. starting over. [closed]